# How to retrieve the value for different editText through database using hashmap

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse

I want to retrieve the data dealer's name customer's name and Pcs from `HashMap` to `EditText` and then want to update delivery status and remarks in the same table .Please tell me if I am doing something wrong.

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";
    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";
    private static final String TABLE_TRACK = "track";
    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    // Track Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_UIDTRACK = "idtrack";
    private static final String KEY_DOCKETNO = "docketno";
    private static final String KEY_DEALERNAME = "dealername";
    private static final String KEY_CUSTOMERNAME = "customername";
    private static final String KEY_PCS = "pcs";
    private static final String KEY_DELIVERY_STATUS = "deliverstatus";
    private static final String KEY_REMARKS = "remarks";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT_TRACK = "created_at_track";
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
        String CREATE_TABLE_TRACK = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRACK + "("
                + KEY_UIDTRACK + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DOCKETNO
                + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DEALERNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CUSTOMERNAME + " TEXT ," + KEY_PCS
                + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DELIVERY_STATUS + " TEXT ,"
                + KEY_REMARKS + " TEXT ," + KEY_CREATED_AT_TRACK + " TEXT"
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TRACK);
    }
    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TRACK);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
    /**
     * Storing AeyeTrack details in database
     * */
    public void addAeyeTrack(Integer idtrack, Integer docketno,
            String dealername, String customername, Integer pcs,
            String deliverstatus, String remarks, String created_at_track) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_UIDTRACK, idtrack); // idtrack
        values.put(KEY_DOCKETNO, docketno); // docketno
        values.put(KEY_DEALERNAME, dealername); // dealername
        values.put(KEY_CUSTOMERNAME, customername); // customername
        values.put(KEY_PCS, pcs); // pcs
        values.put(KEY_DELIVERY_STATUS, deliverstatus); // deliverstatus
        values.put(KEY_REMARKS, remarks); // remarks
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT_TRACK, created_at_track); // created_at_track
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_TRACK, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
    /**
     * Getting update AeyeTrack data from database
     * */
    public boolean updateAeyeTrack(Integer idtrack, Integer docketno,
            String dealername, String customername, Integer pcs,
            String deliverstatus, String remarks, String created_at_track) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_UIDTRACK, idtrack); // idtrack
        contentValues.put(KEY_DOCKETNO, docketno); // docketno
        contentValues.put(KEY_DEALERNAME, dealername); // dealername
        contentValues.put(KEY_CUSTOMERNAME, customername); // customername
        contentValues.put(KEY_PCS, pcs); // pcs
        contentValues.put(KEY_DELIVERY_STATUS, deliverstatus); // deliverstatus
        contentValues.put(KEY_REMARKS, remarks); // remarks
        contentValues.put(KEY_CREATED_AT_TRACK, created_at_track); // created_at_track
        db.update("track", contentValues, "idtrack = ? ",
                new String[] { Integer.toString(idtrack) });
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Getting AeyeTrack data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getAeyeTrackDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> AeyeTrack = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TRACK;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            AeyeTrack.put("idtrack", cursor.getString(1));
            AeyeTrack.put("docketno", cursor.getString(2));
            AeyeTrack.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            AeyeTrack.put("dealername", cursor.getString(4));
            AeyeTrack.put("customername", cursor.getString(5));
            AeyeTrack.put("pcs", cursor.getString(6));
            AeyeTrack.put("deliverstatus", cursor.getString(7));
            AeyeTrack.put("remarks", cursor.getString(8));
            AeyeTrack.put("created_at_track", cursor.getString(9));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return AeyeTrack;
    }
    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }
    /**
     * Getting user login status return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }
    /**
     * Re create database Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.delete(TABLE_TRACK, null, null);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >
        <!-- DocketNo. TextField -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Docket_no" />
        <!-- DocketNo. EditField -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Docket_number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />
        <!-- Submit Button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="158dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit" />
        <!-- Dealer_name TextField -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Dealer_name" />
        <!-- Dealer_name. EditField -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Dealr_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <!-- Customer_name TextField -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Customer_name" />
        <!-- Customer_name EditField -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Custmer_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <!-- Pcs TextField -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Pcs" />
        <!-- Pcs EditField -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Pcs_edit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <!-- Delivery_Status TextField -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Delivery_Status" />
        <!-- Delivery_Status. EditField -->
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/Delivery_Status_arrays"
            android:prompt="@string/Delivery_Status_prompt" />
        <!-- Remarks TextField -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Remarks" />
        <!-- Remarks_Edit EditField -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Remarks_Edit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <!-- "Next" Button -->
        <!-- Cancel Button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Next"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: http://dilipdevelopment.blogspot.in/2012/05/creeate-database-in-android-using.html

Comment: How to get the data from hashmap to edittext @ ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: @PoonamKukreti: please share relevant part of code where you are calling `getAeyeTrackDetails()` method ?

Comment: @PoonamKukreti: where you are calling getAeyeTrackDetails() method ?

Comment: @PoonamKukreti u can retrive hashmap data on the basis of it's key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way you can get it is by reading keys of HashMap();

```
DatabaseHandler d = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        HashMap<String, String> getdetails = d.getUserDetails();
        String name = getdetails.get("name");
        String email = getdetails.get("email");
        String uid = getdetails.get("uid");
        String created_at = getdetails.get("created_at");

        System.out.println("Name-->" + name);
        System.out.println("Email-->" + email);
        System.out.println("UID-->" + uid);
        System.out.println("Created At-->" + created_at);
```

After getting all the values, you can set them to your desired EditText

NOTE: put this code in the onCreate method of Activity in which you are having EditText, but after initialization of EditTexts
You can use the same for getting docket details

Answer (score 0):

try this :

Docket_number.setText(yourHashMap.get("key"));